# python leaves line after printing function

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, terminal, module

I am building a python module as follows. You use it by writing this:

```
from color import *

print(color('none', 'red', 'blue') + 'works?')
print(color('none', 'red', 'green') + 'works still?')
```

The code uses escape codes and works like this:

```
def color(style, fore, bg):

    a = "\033[0;"
    b = "39;"
    c = "49m"

    #styles
    if style == "none":
        a = "\033[0;"

    #fore
    if fore == "none":
        b = "39;"

    #background
    if bg == "none":
        c = "48m"

#finish
    return(a + b + c)
```

Everything works fine except the background color sometimes prints an extra line as shown below [image: screenshot]

The line saying 'works still' should be green but is instead blue.

Any ideas how to fix this? (I can provide more code if needed

Comment: `print(color('none', 'red', 'blue') + 'works\?') ` Could you try this?
`print(color('none', 'red', 'green') + 'works still\?')`

Comment: Yes it does, if you submit it as answer I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(color('none', 'red', 'blue') + 'works\?') 
print(color('none', 'red', 'green') + 'works still\?')
```

It seems it is an escape character issue, I am glad it worked out for you.